# How to align the text on the bottom of the div

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have two div as below (logo and admin):

```
<body id="main_body">
<div id="logo_area">
<div id="logo">
  <image></image>
</div>
<div id="admin">
  LOG IN
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

If I want the admin align next the bottom of the div. That is, it looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
IMAGE
                                  LOG IN
--------------------------------------------
```

I tried the following CSS and it doesn't work.

```
#main_body {
margin:0px;
}

#logo_area {
background-color: #086A87;
height: 60px;
}

#logo {
padding-left:10px;
float:left;
width:80%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#admin {
bottom:0px;
}
```

Can anyone shed some light here please?

Thanks

Comment: try to create a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `#logo_area` and `position:absolute` to `#admin`

```
#logo_area {
background-color: #086A87;
height: 60px; position:relative
}
#admin {
bottom:0; position:absolute; right:0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GrMPc/1/)**

*[**Here is the detailed explanation about absolute and relative position**](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)*

Comment: Thanks it works! Can you explain a little more detail? I am fairly new to css and doesn't quite understand the how to position (relative and absolute) work?

Comment: @Kintarō Given the link for that. There is visual explanation so you can understand easily

Answer (score 0):

Just Add float:left; to the login CSS

```
#main_body {
margin:0px;
}

#logo_area {
background-color: #086A87;
height: 60px;
}

#logo {
padding-left:10px;
float:left;
width:80%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#admin {
bottom:0px;
float:left;
}
```

Consider correct dimensions for the box and all divs inside, you set width:80%; for the logo, then, the remaining is 20% or is less for the login, you need to define this also:

```
#admin{
 width: 20%;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/CrcGU/

It seems that I misunderstood:
Simply remove float:left; from #logo and add float:right; to the Login

```
#logo {
padding-left:10px;
width:80%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:navy;
}

#admin {
bottom:0px;
float:right;
width:15%;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/V6H5x/

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
<div id="image">Some image here...</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Login</li>
        <li>Sign Up</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
#image {
float:left;}

.clear {
clear:both;}


#menu {
float:right;}

#menu ul li {
display:inline;
margin:0px 10px 0px 0px}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LMabugay37/T62rW/2/embedded/result/)**